# deserialize object(s) using binary formatter in c#

Tags: c#, android, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

I have serialized text file from (`Java/android`). I need to `deserialize` this text file using `c#` binary formatter . but I face an error tell me that the input stream is not in `binary format`. kindly note this file is stored and restored from `amazonS3`

Comment: Well if its a text file then you don't want to try and de serialize binary... you need an interoperable serialization format.

Comment: will? how could I find that ?

Comment: Well you need to know what format you've written the file in the first place...

Comment: but the problem is I have already users with there own data that is serialized using java serilizer....!!!

Comment: What sort of format are you producing using the Java Serializer? XML? SOAP? JSON? Binary?... once you know that, you can find the appropriate C# one, if one is available. If not you'll have to write your own.